# Como forçar o download de um arquivo de texto?

Tags: php

Como forçar o download de um arquivo de texto?

Tenho esse código porém não é feito o download, quando clico no link seu contéudo é exibido pelo navegador.

```
<?php

include "conecte.php";

$querymail = mysql_query("select cod,name from usuarios");
fopen("listar.txt", "w+");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($querymail)) {
    $log = str_pad($data[0], 30, " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
    $log2 = str_pad($data[1], 30, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
    if (!$savelog = fopen('listar.txt', "a")){
        exit;
    }        
    if (!fwrite($savelog, $log . $log2. "\r\n")){
        exit; fclose($savelog); 
    }
}
?>


<a href="listar.txt">Clique aqui para baixar</a>
```

Comment: Qual é a sua dúvida?

Comment: Colega, o arquivo será criado onde estiver seu PHP. Para baixar é só clicar em salvar como ali no final. Qual é a dúvida?

Comment: Preciso baixar o arquivo gerado em uma pasta no pc quando clicar em (Clique aqui para baixar) ? Como está ele somente abre no navegador...

Comment: O servidor não tem conhecimento das pastas do cliente, logo o arquivo vai para a pasta padrão de download definida pelo navegador.

Comment: Já observei na pasta padrão download e não consta...

Comment: O texto é exibido em uma página quando clica no link isso? o correto seria fazer o download??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie um novo arquivo(download.php) nele defina o cabeçalho a ser enviado ou seja em qual formato o navegador deve interpretar a informação abra o arquivo e envie para o cliente.

download.php

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=lista.txt');
header('Content-type: text/plain');
$str = file_get_contents('log/lista.txt');
echo $str;
```

Chamada:

```
<a href="download.php">Clique aqui para baixar</a>
```

Um opção mais otimizadada, citada pelo [Wallace Maxters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4995/wallace-maxters) é trocar `file_get_contents()` por `readfile()`

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=lista.txt');
header('Content-type: text/plain');
readfile('log/lista.txt');
```

**Relacionado:**

[PHP readfile vs. file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20095175/1342547)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: Rray, se importa com uma sugestão? Usar `file_get_contents` seguido de um `echo` é um pouco de desperdício de memória (dependendo do tamanho do arquivo). `file_get_contents` lê o arquivo e retorna sua string, e no seu caso, salva numa variável. Nesse caso, utilize `readfile` que já lề o arquivo imprimindo o conteúdo imediatamente, sem armazenar nada em memória

Comment: @WallaceMaxters `readfile(file_get_contents('log/lista.txt'));` ?

Comment: Não, é assim: `readfile('log/lista.txt')`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters isso :D, foda q documentação do php ta bloqueada aqui kkk wtf O.o?

Comment: Quem sabe você mesmo responda: [Qual é a diferença entre readfile e file_get_contents?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126718/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-readfile-e-file-get-contents)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters LOL olha a edição

Comment: Linka eu ae também, kkkkk

Answer (score 2):

A questão foi respondida, mas existe uma outra solução ou complemento. Você pode utilizar o atributo `download` numa tag `a`:

```
<a href="LocalDoArquivo" download="NomeDoArquivo"> Texto </a>
```

Exemplo:

```html
<a href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122672/como-for%c3%a7ar-o-download-de-um-arquivo-de-texto" download="Baixou ao invés de acessar"> Baixar </a>
```

Essa forma você irá baixar o HTML dessa página, ao invés de acessar normalmente.

Isso é novo, inserido no HTML 5!

**Suporte:**

```
Chrome: 14.0+
Internet Explorer: 13.0+
Mozilla: 20.0+
Safari: Não suportado
Opera: 15.0+
```

Comment: +1, eu acho uma ideia bacana, se for no caso de alguém que use apenas o `HTML` , por exemplo