# Qual é a diferença entre readfile e file_get_contents?

Tags: php

No PHP, existem inúmeros meios de se ler o conteúdo de um arquivo.

Existe as funções `fopen`, `file`, `file_get_contents`, `readfile`, e até uma classe chamada `SplFileObject`.

- `file` lê linha por linha e põe elas num `array`.
- `fopen` lê o arquivo e cria um `resource` para ser manipulado com outras funções, como `fgets` e `fwrite`.
- SplFileObject é semelhante a `fopen` e afins, porém você tem tudo isso mesclado com a funcionalidade dos `Iterators`.

Porém eu gostaria de saber qual é a diferença entre `readfile` e `file_get_contents`. Pois eu sei que essas últimas leem todo o conteúdo do arquivo, diferente das outras.

Mas por que então ter as duas funções? Existe alguma diferença entre elas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`file_get_contents()` carrega o arquivo inteiro em memória, o que pode ser um problema com grandes arquivos. Costuma ser muito útil quando você precisa tratar os valores retornados de um arquivo (por exemplo, se você quer fazer um `json_decode` num arquivo que json que você acabou de abrir).

`readfile()` faz tres coisas, lê o arquivo passado, escreve o resultado direto no buffer e o retorno da função é o número de bytes do arquivo.

Comment: Essa última informação do número de bytes eu desconhecia +1

Comment: Dei um upgrade aí na parte do `file_get_contents`, pois se não fica parecendo que ele "é ruim" e que `readfile`  "é bom".

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não seria `json_encode()`? o decode vc geralmente armazena, o encode geralmente não. ex: `$json = json_encode($str); echo $json;`, vira `readfile(json_encode($str))` seria isso?

Comment: Não, quero dizer se você quer decodificar um arquivo `json`

Comment: Por exemplo, é útil para abrir o `composer.json` e transformá-lo num `array` em Php :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters agora entendi, haha estou com o `readfile()` na cabeça xD se fosse p fazer um `fopen()/fgets()` no lugar `file_get_contetns()` para decodificar o json era de lascar.