# Estou tentando gerar um arquivo pdf com php, porém gera um arquivo corrompido

Tags: php, pdf

Segue o código do arquivo para exibir o pdf.
Esse pdf é salvo no banco de dados. Em uma máquina com php antigo ele funciona. Porém no servidor online ele gera o arquivo pdf corrompido.

```
<?php

if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $file = $banco = $banco->GetRow("SELECT * FROM up_danf WHERE id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'");
}

if (!empty($file['nome'])) {
    header("Content-Type: application/" . $file["tipo"] . "");
    header("Content-Length: " . $file["tamanho"] . "");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $file["nome"] . "");
    header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");
    header('Cache-Control: private');
    header('Pragma: private');

    header("Expires: 0");
    session_cache_limiter('public');

    print $file["conteudo_arquivo"];
}
?>
```

---

Coloquei o comando 
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
e comentei  header("Expires: 0");

continuou sem funcionar.

talvez ajude a versão do php que estou utilizando é: 
PHP Version 5.3.17

Comment: As vezes isso acontece devido a html ou outra saída de texto que vai junto, verifique isso. Relacionado: [Qual é a diferença entre readfile e file_get_contents?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126718/91)

Comment: Faz um teste adicionando este cabeçalho com data no passado header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); Se der certo retorna um feedback aqui pra gente, já passei por este problema e tem a ver com o controle de cache do browser. Usei o cabeçalho com expires no passado e imprimiu o PDF.

Comment: Coloquei o comando header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); e comentei header("Expires: 0");

continuou sem funcionar.

talvez ajude a versão do php que estou utilizando é: PHP Version 5.3.17

Comment: Comente a linha `header("Content-Type: application/" . $file["tipo"] . "");`, é provavel que seja algum problema ao imprimir (`print $`) e não nos headers.

Comment: comentei a linha, e também não funcionou.